# How to get default RAS phone book path of the current user?

Tags: c++, winapi

How to get default RAS phone book file (.pbk) path through WinAPI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get default RAS phone book file (.pbk) path through WinAPI?

There seems no such API.

The **default phone-book file** is the one selected by the user in the User Preferences property sheet of the Dial-Up Networking dialog box.

You can find it at:

```
%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\PBK
```

Refer to [Creating and Configuring Network Connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/orphan-topics/ws.10/cc731864(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN).